# Launch particular screen using Push Notification in Oracle MAF

Tags: oracle, jdeveloper, oracle-maf, mcs

I have implemented push notification in Oracle MAF using Oracle MCS. It works fine. Currently when somebody clicks the notification application opens to the default screen(to the home screen). Is it possible to access / open particular screen from push notification other than the default screen?? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `AdfmfContainerUtilities.goToFeature("<featureName>")` in your `onMessage()` method of `PushEventListener` class. When you click the notification it will take you to the feature specified.